# Modify this JS Focus function to work with PHP function which dynamically sets Select options

Tags: php, javascript, focus

This `focus` function allows me to manipulate the value of Select element options in Javascript, and I need to create a similar function to use with the PHP function below.

In *Form 1* I pre-select the most commonly chosen options for 300+ Select elements, and the function (a combination of JS & jQuery) allows me to differentiate between when those values are still in their initial pre-selected/default state vs. when a user has actively chosen that value by clicking on the form element (indicating that they made an active decision to leave it set to that value). I've posted a fiddle with a working example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/JHAPp/4/

I'm having trouble creating a similar function in PHP to use on the customer account page (which allows users to edit their information). The code below allows me to properly pre-select the values matching the information in the db, but I don't know how to modify the code so that it will submit the default value when the user hasn't focused on the element. Unlike in 1rst form, I can't change the actual values in the $options array manually because they may have already selected a value for that field. (at the moment I'm just removing "_default" in order to get it to work).

I'm guessing that I probably need something similar to the original function, but using the value fetched instead of the $options array values, so that I can POST that one if the element hasn't been focused.

**Form 1 - HTML & JS Function**

```
<select name="jeans">
    <option value="$0">$0</option>
    <option value="$50_default" selected="selected">$50</option>
    <option value="$100">$100</option>
    <option value="$150">$150</option>
</select>

$('select').focus(function () {
    var option = $(this).find("option[value*=default]");
    option.attr('value', option.attr('value').replace(/_default/g, ''));
});
```

**Form 2 - HTML & PHP**

```
<?php
    try {  
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM price WHERE user_id = :user_id");  
        $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id); 
        $stmt->execute();
    }  catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $search_default = array('_default');
    $replace_default = array('');
    $row_default = str_replace($search_default, $replace_default, $row);
    // Pre-selects the option matching the db information
    function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $currentSelection) {
        foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
            echo '<option ' . (($key == $currentSelection) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
        }
    }
?>
<select name="jeans">
<?php
    // Generates a `Select` element 
    $options = array("Null"=>"", "$0"=>"$0", "$50"=>"$50", "$100"=>"$100", "$150"=>"$150");
    $selected = $row_default['jeans'];
    // Pre-selects the option matching the db information
    echo printSelectOptions($options, $selected); 
?> 
</select>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the last line of the question, the _"modify the code so that it will submit the default value when they haven't touched the element"_ part. I can see that `PHP` is generating `HTML` and there is also a `JavaScript` function which removes the `_default` on focus. But am unsure on the _submit_ part and exactly what the problem is. A `<form>` **POST** will submit all [successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls).

Comment: @andyb - I just edited the question, so hopefully it's a bit clearer now. It's always a bit tricky drafting questions when I'm not clear of the direction to take to solve them ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused so here's how I imagine the stack. There's some `PHP` code that pulls prices from a database and generates a `<select>`. One of the `<option>` elements is _"selected"_ based on some criteria. The output of this `PHP` code is some `HTML` that is delivered to the browser. A person interacts with the `<select>` either leaving the existing value selected or selecting a new one. When they finish, the `<form>` is _submitted_ via HTTP POST back to a `PHP` page which reads the POST data and saves the options back to the database. Please correct if I'm wrong! :-D

Comment: @andyb - Now I understand the confusion :-) The php generates a <select> element based on the '$options = array("..."), and the printSelectOptions function selects the option matching the value in the db (in this case either '$50' or '$50_default')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer, courtesy of the amazing @JohnS :-)

```
// This is a helper function that replaces a key while maintaining the entry's
// position in the array. It does not modify the given array, but returns a
// new array.
function replaceKey($array, $oldKey, $newKey) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[($key === $oldKey) ? $newKey : $key] = $value;
    }
    return $newArray;
}

$options = array("Null"=>"", "$0"=>"$0", "$50"=>"$50", "$100"=>"$100", "$150"=>"$150");

// We will change the key for the entry in $options so it includes "_default" if
// the value from the database includes "_default". We need to do this only if
// $row['jeans'] ends with "_default". That will be the case if these two are
// different.
if ($row_default['jeans'] !== $row['jeans']) {
    $options = replaceKey($options, $row_default['jeans'], $row['jeans']);
}

// Now we can use the value from the db for setting the selected value, rather
// than the value that had "_default" removed. 
$selected = $row['jeans'];

// Pre-selects the option matching the db information.
echo printSelectOptions($options, $selected);
```

I learned the hard way that this doesn't work with the two jQuery plugins that I use for styling `<select>` elements *([jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) and [Dropkick](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick))* since neither plugin support the `focus` event or the standard `click` event.

I modified the JS function to use the [MultiSelect Widget](http://erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)'s custom `open`event, and have posted a fiddle with the new function here http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/dFyMq/

```
$(select).multiselect({ 
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var option = $(this).find("option[value*=default]");
        option.attr('value', option.attr('value').replace(/_default/g, ''));
        $(select).multiselect("refresh")
    }
});
```

Using it with [Dropkick](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick) was a lot more complicated, and I've posted a fiddle with the method I used here: http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/yhAX5/4/. This workaround required creating 2 sets of `<select>` elements - one set uses standard elements and is hidden *(`display:none`)*, and another set that uses Dropkick and is visible to the user. It also uses the `change()` method and therefore doesn't modify the value if the user clicks on the dropdown box and then consciously decides to leave the 'default' value.